# Hive not starting on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: hadoop, hive

On Ubuntu 16.04, I use hive 2.3.2 and hadoop 2.7.1 and I had this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUBinary.getRequiredData(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
    at com.ibm.icu.charset.UConverterAlias.haveAliasData(UConverterAlias.java:131)
    at com.ibm.icu.charset.UConverterAlias.getCanonicalName(UConverterAlias.java:525)
    at com.ibm.icu.charset.CharsetProviderICU.getICUCanonicalName(CharsetProviderICU.java:126)
    at com.ibm.icu.charset.CharsetProviderICU.charsetForName(CharsetProviderICU.java:62)
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you running and which one does Hive require?

Comment: @k0pernikus my java version is 1.8.0 and hive needs 1.7 or newer

Comment: you can use JDK9 or hive 2.1, maybe hive2.3 is build with JDK9. refer to [https://github.com/plasma-umass/doppio/issues/497](https://github.com/plasma-umass/doppio/issues/497)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue. On ubuntu 16.04, hive 2.3.3, hadoop 2.9.0.

com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUBinary class is in icu4j jar in hive/lib

Hive was shipped with icu4j-4.8.1.jar, but ICUBinary class in icu4j-4.8.1 doesn't contain the getRequiredData method.

Checked the latest version of icu4j (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j) and found that the method is present.

Replaced the icu4j jar in hive/lib with the latest version and it started working !